# Ember 2.7: Remove button if I am on a nested route

Tags: ember.js

My goal is to have the posts.index show a list of your posts and a button to add a new post above your list of current posts. I have a button ("Add new post") that I want to disappear once that button renders the posts.new template in the `{{outlet}}`

My Router

```
{{router.js}}

Router.map(function() {
  ...
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

Posts.index template

```
{{templates/posts.hbs}}

{{outlet}} {{!-- <- Contains the posts.new template --}}
{{#if showButton}}
  <p>works</p>
{{else}}
  <p>doesn't</p>
{{/if}}
{{#link-to 'posts.new' tagName='button' class="btn btn-default"}}Add a new post{{/link-to}}
```

controller

```
{{controllers/posts.js}}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  posts: Ember.inject.controller(),
  showButton: Ember.computed.equal('posts.index', 'posts.new'),
});
```

Right now `showButton` is returning 'doesn't' on both routes because I am not using the `computed.equal` helper correctly. What I am trying to do is check if the current route is matching up to the `posts.new` route and if it is, display the block of code I desire.

Edit:

I figured out the answer to my own question. Here it is to anyone else who needs it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819256/4761914

Comment: computed equal compares the first property with a string, in your case it will always be false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixes the issue. Now it checks if the `currentRouteName` is equal to the route I want (`'posts.new'` in this case). If it does, it returns `true` and I can use that logic on my template.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  application: Ember.inject.controller(),
  onNewRoute: Ember.computed.equal('application.currentRouteName', 'posts.new'),

});
```